# Rails controllers not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, passenger, dreamhost

I've just started on rails, got it all setup on my DreamHost account with Passenger, except the demo controller I've created isn't working. I ran:

```
$ script/generate controller demo index
```

The files are all there, but when I go to http://rails.mysite.com/demo/index I get the 'We're sorry, but something went wrong' message. There's nothing in the log files at all, I'm in development mode.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Darren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have initialized your database yet, in which case the Rails stack doesn't finish booting properly. If you can run script/console, then you're half-way there. If you can't, it may give you a hint as to what's wrong.

Generally the database.yml file contains a configuration for sqlite3, but that may not be available on your platform. It's pretty easy to switch that over to MySQL or Postgres, whatever you're using.

Comment: $ script/console
    Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.5)
    >> 

Looks good, the db is setup, it's MySQL but I've already configured that. It's just annoying that it's dying silently!

Comment: It was a database issue after all. I started over and got an error message, turns out I was in production when my database was only configured for development. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you map it in `routes.rb`?

Try something like:

```
map.connect "/demo/", :controller => "demo", :action => "index"
```

Comment: I didn't think you had to map every controller that you make?

Comment: There are default routes, usually, that pick these up, but it's always a good idea to map your own using map.resource